# Check if a dlc is activated in the current campaign in xcom

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Is it possible to check if a dlc is active in the current campaign?

And if a dlc is not active, is it possible to activate it during the campaign?

Comment: I know the answer to the second question is no. Not sure about the first one.

Comment: The only way I know to check would be to check for new features from the DLC. Did the armor customization options come with the DLC, or was that in an update to the original game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, DLCs cannot be activated if they were not enabled when the game was started.

As for how to check, it depends on what you mean.

For the added storylines (Slingshot and Progeny):

- You can check the Barracks/Memorial. Both Progeny and Slingshot give you unique soldiers: Slingshot has Shaojie Zhang, and Progeny has Annette Durand.
- You can just wait. No, really. Friends in Low Places and Portent are both in April-ish. Confounding Light and Gangplank are about one month after that. Deluge and Furies are shortly after XCOM Base Defense.
- Almost certainly in the save file somewhere. Nobody knows for sure because the format is undocumented.

As for the Enemy Within DLC:

1. Go to the main menu.
2. Does the gigantic subtitle say "Enemy Within"?
3. There's your answer.

If you launch in vanilla, you can't load EW save files. If you launch in EW, you can't load vanilla save files.

Comment: Wow. Not every day that you answer a year-old question and have it accepted in 8 hours ^_^